# Possible to hide Gmail sub-labels when another sub-label is visible?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I've already set to hide labels if there are no unread messages.

However, if >1 or more sub-labels as an unread message, the entire hierarchy of that set of labels becomes visible.

Is there a way to set it to strictly only show a sub-label if only that label has unread messages?

[image: Gmail filters expanded folder]